# How to display a sentence containing HTML throughout with React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, string-interpolation

I'm building with react and I want to display JSON data returned from a get request to the user.  The JSON data contains string values which are made up of sentences with html appearing within the sentences.  For example:

`[{ "sentence" : "Don't look at the <span> sun </span> directly with your <span>eye</span>s, it's <span>risk</span>y!"}]`

My goal is for the text to render normally, but the html within the string to be rendered as html alongside the text, thus allowing me to manipulate the html so I can do things like highlight particular words within the sentence with CSS. Currently I just get the data from a get request, save it to state and display it through props like normal.

```
return (
    <div>{props.data.sentence}</div>
);
```

However if I take this value from my props and just try to include it directly in the view, it will just display the whole thing as a string thus showing the user the actual HTML code.

Can someone tell me how to display this kind of string + html combo in React?

Comment: Please read about XSS and DOM-based XSS before you do this. And you might want to also have a look at [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify)

Answer (score 1):

Use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.data.sentence}}></div>
```

Comment: FYI, data in your question is the array, so you may need to indicate data[0].sentence